# Calculate Weighted Average and Weighted Standard Deviation in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This is something I have never attempted before

I want to calculate the weighted standard deviation and the weighted average for the dataset containing records for actual values measured against set values

The calculation is to be done using a DAX query in PowerBI

| Set Value 1 | Actual Value 1 | Set Value 2 | Actual Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 101 | 102 |
| 10 | 11 | 101 | 104 |
| 10 | 12 | 101 | 97 |
| 10 | 7 | 101 | 99 |
| 10 | 13 | 101 | 97 |
| 10 | 13 | 101 | 100 |
| 10 | 9 | 101 | 98 |
| 10 | 10 | 101 | 100 |
| 10 | 8 | 101 | 102 |
| 10 | 14 | 101 | 98 |
| 10 | 8 | 101 | 98 |
| 10 | 13 | 101 | 96 |
| 10 | 13 | 101 | 103 |
| 10 | 14 | 101 | 102 |
| 10 | 7 | 202 | 205 |
| 20 | 18 | 202 | 198 |
| 20 | 18 | 202 | 197 |
| 20 | 19 | 202 | 203 |
| 20 | 19 | 202 | 202 |
| 20 | 19 | 202 | 201 |
| 20 | 22 | 202 | 202 |
| 20 | 18 | 202 | 200 |
| 20 | 17 | 202 | 195 |
| 20 | 23 | 202 | 198 |

Edit 1:
Please use the data above.
Also, please note that although, set points are what we intend to use as weights but its the count of a particular set point. for eg: if the setpoint1 10 is repeating 15 times and set point1 20 is repeating 9 times then wieght to be used as 15 & 9 respectively

Comment: Please post your expected output as well

Comment: can you post your sample data as a machine readable table? It's enough to copy paste the table from power bi to this site https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/ and then to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted Average and Standard deviation can be implemented in DAX according to their mathematical definition.

Assuming we have a table with the columns Weight and Value the formula for the Weighted Average is

```
WAvg = 
VAR Num = SUMX( Samples, Samples[Weight] * Samples[Value] )
VAR Den = SUM( Samples[Weight] )
RETURN DIVIDE( Num, Den )
```

and the formula for the Weighted Standard Deviation is

```
WStdDev = 
VAR WAvg = [WAvg]
VAR Num = SUMX( Samples, Samples[Weight] * (Samples[Value] - Wavg)^2 )
VAR Den = SUM( Samples[Weight] )
VAR WVar = DIVIDE( Num, Den )
RETURN SQRT(WVar)
```

Edit:
if I understand your new request, the Weight is the number of rows with the same Set Value, that is to be used for each of the Actual Value. Then, since there are two pairs of columns, I assume that the requirement is to have a set of measures per each couple of columns.

The formula requires to add a count of the number of rows per each group of Set Value, to be used as weight. I imported the sample table as table "V"

Weighted average for Set Value 1 and Actual Value 1

```
WAvg1 = 
VAR Num =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 1] ) ) * V[Actual Value 1]
    )
VAR Den =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 1] ) )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE( Num, Den )
```

Weighted average for Set Value 2 and Actual Value 2

```
WAvg2 = 
VAR Num =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 2] ) ) * V[Actual Value 2]
    )
VAR Den =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 2] ) )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE( Num, Den )
```

Weighted standard deviation for Set Value 1 and Actual Value 1

```
WStdDev1 = 
VAR Num =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        VAR WAvg = [WAvg1]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 1] ) ) * ( V[Actual Value 1] - WAvg ) ^ 2
    )
VAR Den =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 1] ) )
    )
VAR WVariance =
    DIVIDE( Num, Den )
RETURN 
    SQRT( WVariance )
```

Weighted standard deviation for Set Value 2 and Actual Value 2

```
WStdDev2 = 
VAR Num =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        VAR WAvg = [WAvg2]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 2] ) ) * ( V[Actual Value 2] - WAvg ) ^ 2
    )
VAR Den =
    SUMX(
        ALL( V ),
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( V ), ALLEXCEPT( V, V[Set Value 2] ) )
    )
VAR WVariance =
    DIVIDE( Num, Den )
RETURN
    SQRT( WVariance )
```

Applying these formulas to the sample table we get these results

[image: visual card with results]

Comment: Although Thanks a lot for this Answer:  But please refer to edit 1: as I was expecting a different

Comment: If I understood your new request I added the solution to my answer. Please, check the results to see if they are what you expected.

Comment: Can you please clarify how get a single value, considering the two pairs of columns? Actual Value 1 and Actual Value 2 contain two pretty different range of values to be considered the same kind of dataset.